# structure php array with db data

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array returned from db with this structure:

```
[0] array(2) {
  ["Brand"] "A"
  ["Family"] "B"
}
[1] array(2) {
  ["Brand"] "A"
  ["Family"] "C"
}
[2] array(2) {
  ["Brand"] "A"
  ["Family"] "D"
}
[3] array(2) {
  ["Brand"] "B"
  ["Family"] "ABC"
}
[4] array(2) {
  ["Brand"] "B"
  ["Family"] "DD"
}
```

I need to create an array like so:

```
[0] array(2) {
  ["Brand"] "A" array() {
    "B",
    "C",
    "D"
}
[1] array(2) {
  ["Brand"] "B" array() {
    "ABC",
    "DD"
}
```

So basically, the Brand should be unique and inside each brand i need a list of families.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following, `$mainarray` is the array you have now

```
$brand = array();
foreach($mainarray as $v){
    $brand['Brand'][$v['Brand']][] = $v['Family'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple array recursion exercise.

Here's some PHP pseudo code:

```
$output = array();

foreach($array as $i){
//loop through the array returned from the db

$output[$i["brand"]] = array_unique(array_merge($output[$i["brand"]], array($i["Family"])));
//merge the existing families for the brand with the current iteration's, and maintain a set datastructure (no duplicate entries for each family)
}

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you required:

```
<?php

$array1=array(array('Brand'=>'A','Family'=>'B'), array('Brand'=>'A','Family'=>'C'), array('Brand'=>'A','Family'=>'D'), array('Brand'=>'B','Family'=>'ABC'), array('Brand'=>'B','Family'=>'DD'));


$brand=array();

        foreach($array1 as $value=>$data){
            foreach($data as $value2=>$data2){
                if($value2=='Family'):
                    if($value<3):
                    $brand['Brand']['A'][]=$data2;
                    else:
                    $brand['Brand']['B'][]=$data2;
                    endif;
                endif;
            }
        }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($brand);
echo "</pre>";  

?>
```